# Custom js added in custom module in magento

Tags: magento-2.0

I have created a module. In this a custom js file is added with requirejs-config.js, But to load the js file, I need to write the following lines on phtml,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery','customjs']});</script>
```

If I don't add the above line js is not adding .Can some body please tell is this the right approach or I am doing some thing wrong.
Require js code added at (Namespace\Modulename\view\frontend)

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'mage/template',
    ], function (
        $,
        _,
        template
    ) {

        //custom code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is the right approach. because you have created custom.js right . so that custom.js you need to call in your requirejs-config.js

But now when you want to use this actuall js functions and properties you need to pass below code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery','customjs']});</script>
```

What it mean actually , to load your **customjs** it requires jquery so first load the jquery then load your customjs and then you can pass the parameters.

```
require([ 'jquery', 'customjs'], function(){
        alert("test");
     });
```

so alert box will prompt when you add this in your template

**Jfyi** - in your **requirejs-config.js** you need to write like below code you dont'need to write extension of js file like.js as require js automatically render that . and lastly put the js file in **web/js** folder in your module

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            "customjs": "Vendor_Modulename/js/custom"
        }
    }
};
```